# live view of terminal input and output from another terminal and machine?

Tags: command-line, logs

I work maintaining Linux, Windows, Mac machines at a business. When something goes wrong we check logs and sometimes these logs need more context like what command was typed what was the output of that command to the user at the same time as I receive a change in `/var/log/messages`. I need to be able to do this because workers are experiencing an issue we can't track and it's hard for them to stop work so I can pull up the history command and logs and try to compare what was typed when the issue occurred.

I want to be able to keep a rolling log (perhaps similar to `top`) of the commands entered along with their outputs that I can view from my machine thats `ssh`'d in from a different room while the artist gets to work uninterrupted so that I can view the issue they are experiencing in real time and compare that to my `/var/log/messages` and find a solution because none of the manufacturers of the equipment were using are reporting any issues nor know how to deal with these "random phantom" failures we keep having.